# C# - How can I test if an image file is damaged or corrupted without it thowing an Exception?

Tags: c#

So I am making an app (Windows Form) that makes it much easier to sort images into correct folders. It starts off by collecting the Paths of all the image files inside a specified folder. It stores those paths in a List.

```
private void FindAndListAllImagesInAFolder(string sourceFolderPath){
        //the list of image extensions I'm looking for
        string[] imageExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".bmp", ".gif" }; // List of image file extensions

        //imageFiles is a List<string> that contains the image paths
        imageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolderPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            .Where(file => imageExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file)))
            .ToList();
    }
```

After that, I then display the image in a picturebox.

```
string imagePath = imageFiles[currentImage];
    
//the picture
using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var image = Image.FromStream(stream)) //This line opens the image file unless it is damaged
    {
         var bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
         pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
         Application.DoEvents();

         // Dispose the previous image from memory (if it exists)
         image.Dispose();
         GC.Collect();
    }
    stream.Close();
}
```

I then use keyboard input to tell the app which folder it should move the currently displayed image to.

Normally, this works fine, but sometimes an image is damaged or corrupted in some way and can't be displayed. The only way for me to KNOW that it is damaged or corrupted is by trying to open it. Only after trying to open the image, can the app determine that it's damaged to which it then throws an exception. (ArgumentException to be exact)

```
catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        //move the banished file to a graveyard list
        graveyardFiles.Add(imageFiles[currentImage]);

        imageFiles.RemoveAt(CurrentImage);

        //Attempt to show the next image in the list
        UpdatePictureData(CurrentImage);
    }
```

I then handle the exception by moving the damaged image path to a different List which i can then later give attention to. Once it has been moved, the app automatically tries to open the next image in the list of image-Paths.

The problem i am battling with is that sometimes, large numbers of image files are damaged. As a result, lots of exceptions are thrown and handled before the app settles on an undamaged image which it can then display. If the amount of damaged images is TOO large, the app just dies for no reason. This makes me think that there might be a critical amount of exceptions that if triggered fast enough might cause the app to terminate.

I don't like using exceptions like that but given the nature of checking if an image is damaged or not, getting an exception is the only reliable way I can think of.

Thus I get back to my original question... How can I test if an image file is damaged or corrupted without it throwing an Exception?

Comment: Do you know why images are corrupted?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see more code. Where is the `try`-block?

Comment: _"the app just dies for no reason. This makes me think that there might be a critical amount of exceptions that if triggered fast enough might cause the app to terminate."_ - TBH never heard of a limit being present on an amount of caught exception.  Better then doing guess work is to find out why the app is crashing. Do you have a [mre] you can share?

Comment: Lots of exceptions can slow down the application, that is a fact. But it definitely shouldn't die completely. Maybe you get another exception while handling the first or so?

Comment: Some test before opening : 
    GIF image files have the ASCII code for "GIF89a" (47 49 46 38 39 61) or "GIF87a" (47 49 46 38 37 61)  ;
    JPEG image files begin with FF D8 and end with FF D9. JPEG/JFIF files contain the ASCII code for "JFIF" (4A 46 49 46) as a null terminated string. ;
    PNG image files begin with an 8-byte signature which identifies the file as a PNG file and allows detection of common file transfer problems: \211 P N G \r \n \032 \n (89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A).